# Creating PDF from UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, pdf, uiview

I have been stuck/ researching this problem for days, the method below successfully creates the pdf from a regular size UIView. However, I need the contents of my containerView that is located inside a UIScrollview. The height of my containerView is 5000. Can someone help me to render the containerView into multiple PDF pages or direct me to a better way of doing this. `func exportAsPdfFromView() -> String {

```
    func screenShotScrollview() -> String {

    let scrollView = waiverViews.scrollView

    let pageDimensions = scrollView.bounds

    let pageSize = pageDimensions.size
    let totalSize = scrollView.contentSize

    let numberOfPagesThatFitVertivally = Int(ceil(totalSize.height/pageSize.height))

    let outputData = NSMutableData()

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(outputData, pageDimensions, nil)

    let savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let savedContentInset = scrollView.contentInset

    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    let origin = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height)

    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {

        for indexVertical in 0..<numberOfPagesThatFitVertivally {

            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(origin, nil)

            let offsetVertical = CGFloat(indexVertical) * pageSize.height

            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: offsetVertical)

            context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -offsetVertical)

            scrollView.layer.render(in: context)

        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()


        scrollView.contentInset = savedContentInset
        scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
    }

    return self.saveViewPdf(data: outputData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a scrollView would not want to render all contents to its layer all the time, until it is being viewed.

I am guessing this is returning just the snapshot of the UIScrollView's current window?

To take multiple snapshots of the whole contentBounds of the UIScrollView, you could potentially, `setTheContentOffset` of the scrollview in its total `contentBounds.height/frame.height` which would return the pages. And then generate PDFs within the loop?

for instance something like this, and then UX wise, hide the scroll view. While this is being generated, unhide it when it is complete.

```
for i in 0..<pages {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(.init(x: 0, y: i*scrollViewHeight))
    //PDF Generation flow
    //set the url to something like "pdf_file_\(i).pdf"
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example of such method? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @WurlLink I provided an example snippet

Comment: Would that work with the method I was already using? Or do I have to try a whole different method all together?

Comment: @WurlLink I need to see what `func saveViewPdf` does to answer that, but essentially it should, if that is writing the pdf data into a file locally

Comment: I've tried your answer and somehow I am only getting the first two pages saved. I have updated my code in my question. I truly appreciate any help I can get.